# Elgato HD60 Pro with Ubuntu?

Tags: video, video-capture-card

I currently have a Windows 10 Pro machine that I would like to move over to Ubuntu in the near future.  I have been researching how the various pieces of software I use as part of my workflow would run on Linux. Most of them would run either on Wine or in a Windows 10 VM, and the one program that won't I can find a Linux equivalent for.

However, my question has more to do with hardware instead of software.  I use an [Elgato HD60 Pro capture card](https://help.elgato.com/hc/en-us/articles/4409964638861-Elgato-Game-Capture-HD60-Pro-Technical-Specifications) to ingest video from various devices. On Windows, the capture card shows up as a video input device, similar to a webcam.

Would it work the same way?  Is there anything similar for Linux?  Or do I have to replace the capture card when I switch to Linux?

Comment: You can boot with a live USB and check it yourself.

Comment: Hadn't thought about that, thanks!

Comment: Wine isn't a good choice for running Windows apps. A W10 VM probably won't have access to the capture card... but try it and see.

Comment: As of 2022-Oct-30, I am not aware of a solution for using the Elgdato HD60 Pro on Linux. The closest I'm aware of is https://github.com/tolga9009/elgato-gchd which supports the Elgato HD, but **not** Elgato HD60 Pro, and that project has been discontinued, so it's unlikely to ever get HD60 Pro support.